# What's the difference between "Try not to blink" and "Try to do not blink"

Tags: word-order, negation, do-support, imperative-sentences

I recently heard:

> Try not to blink.

However I knew the following form:

> Try to do not blink.

Is one of them wrong? What is the difference ?

Comment: The "do" is not grammatical.  Did you mean to ask the difference between *try to not blink* and *try not to blink*?

Comment: DO as an auxiliary is always finite and so is never preceded by 'to'. This is the reason we reject the traditional terms 'verb to do', 'verb to be' etc. It's possible, however, to say "I tried to do the homework", in which case, DO is not an auxiliary, but a lexical verb.

Comment: @user178049 has given the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Google Books Ngram viewer indicates that the construction **try not to...** is about 100 times more common than **try to not...**.

**Try to not** is a form that has appeared gradually over the past half century.

So you occasionally hear people say things like: **Try to not cough so loudly**. However, it's certainly more idiomatic to say **try not to cough so loudly**.

In your second example the insertion of the word **do** is simply wrong. Omit it.

You will find a similar question about the placing of **not** at the site below.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148335/try-not-or-do-not-try
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=try+not+to%2Ctry+to+not

Comment: +1.  But "Do try not to blink" is grammatically correct.  It has a formal tone, and is similar to a reprimand.

Comment: Absolutely! It was OP's example of **Try to do not blink** that I referred it.